# Cloud Dataflow/Beam: Side Input Limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

SideInput is sort of like broadcast in Spark, meaning you are caching data to a local worker machines for fast lookup to reduce network/shuffle overhead. It is logical to think limit to how much memory you can have should fit in heap. In Dataflow [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/limits), it says limit is 20K shard. What does this mean? How big is a shard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your original question, you can configure the amount of in-memory caching done by a Dataflow worker via the `--workerCacheSizeMb` option on the command line, which is [`setWorkerCacheSizeMb`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions.html#setWorkerCacheMb-java.lang.Integer-) if you are invoking a pipeline programmatically. The default is 100Mb.

Comment: Is it possible to assign external disk using instance template in compute with Dataflow? Also an option you mentioned doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.